# Despite not using Mathjax, could we allow for a strict subset of Mathjax that could make it easier to create characters such as ῆ and ō?

Tags: feature-request

The problem: So say somebody wants to create the "*ō*" character without having to copy it from somewhere. Now here's the thing. This might just be a Linux thing, but I seem unable to find a keyboard which can make that symbol. The same thing goes for the "*ῆ*" character. The Greek keyboard seems able to create the base character, but is unable to get *that specific accent on the character*.

---

A possible solution: Allowing for a strict subset of Mathjax to be used, however, this isn't really a viable solution since I found out while on Detexify that every L<sup>A</sup>T<sup>E</sup>X character needs a license to be used. It even says so in the restriction, which honestly sucks:[image]

So, are there any other solutions? I guess so, unless using code snippets would not be a viable option, because not only do they take up a *huge* amount of space in questions, the only way that it *could* be seen as just able to be considered in the slightest part is if it didn't require a license to use, which honestly is very painful in its full.

---

#### My question

---

Is there any theoretical way that this site could use a strict subset of Mathjax, or are we just going to have to stick to copying and pasting characters into our questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Cornflakes about LaTeX not being the solution, but I'd also like to offer some feedback on your particular use case. On Linux (most versions at least), the "English International" keyboard layouts let you type macrons, and you can enable the Compose key (i.e. XCompose) to make them even easier. For me, Compose+`-` (or `_`) will let me put a macron on most letters.

Similarly, ῆ can be typed on any "Polytonic" Greek keyboard—i.e. one that handles the three different types of ancient accents instead of the single modern one. For me, "Greek (polytonic)" makes `[` a dead key for the circumflex, so `[` `h` produces a ῆ.

If you can't add extra keyboard layouts for whatever reason, Lexilogos has "keyboards" for a wide variety of languages and scripts. [Ancient Greek](https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/greek_ancient.htm) will give you the eta with circumflex while [Latin](https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/latin.htm) gives you macrons and breves.

Answer (score 2):

While some sites on the TeX exchange network have LaTeX enabled, this site isn't one of them, and even on linguistics.se there is no LaTeX support. I don't see a convincing argument for LaTeX in the uses cases presented here: These are plain text characters and it is the users' duty to get them in, e.g., by configuring a custom keyboard layout or, as mentioned, by cut-and-paste.

BTW, I think the formulation "every LATEX character needs a license to be used" is at least misleading, if not wrong. It is just that the software is set up as "nagware" that begs for a licence at every use. Of course, characters themselves are not subject to licences (in general, trademarks like the Apple logo in older Apple character sets are a notable exception to this).